# Написание Unit - тестов в Android

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты

Всем привет, пишу тестовое задание на Android - разработчика, и одним из требований является написание нескольких Jnit тестов (которые я ни разу не писал).

Мое приложение реализует паттерн MVP с Moxy.
Я перенес всю структуру в test, и дальше не знаю к чему приступать.

Например, есть в Presenter метод для получения result с api

```
public void getResults(String textSearch){
        mCompositeDisposable.add(ApiUtils.getApi()
                .getResponse(textSearch)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showRefresh())
                .doFinally(() -> mView.hideRefresh())
                .subscribe(
                        response -> {
                            mView.showResults(response.getResults());
                        },
                        throwable -> mView.showError()
                ));
    }
```

Что тут нужно тестировать? Придет результат не того типа? Ну провалится от в ветку throwable и все.

[Ссылка на приложение](https://github.com/danilshik/iTunesStoreApp)

Comment: Вряд ли от вас хотят чтобы вы подобный код тестировали, т.к. это сложно и долго. Скорее всего имеется в виду пара тестов на простые методы с логикой. Например метод фильтрующий что-то (На вход массив, на выход массив и тусты проверяющие что при заданных вариантах входящих массивов будут правильные версии исходящих). А вот подобный вашему код научиться тестировать займёт неделю или 2 времени (это лично моя оценка для лично меня)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну написали просто 3 теста. Но у меня кроме получения данных, и установки видимости объектов и SwipeRefreshLayout больше и ничего нет. А еще есть edittext куда вводят поисковой запрос

Comment: Ну... Тогда не знаю)

Answer (score 0):

Что нужно тестировать ?
Ответ прост - работу данного метода.

Выделяем, только работу данного метода - он получает параметр `textSearch`, отдает его вовне и как результат получает `response` или `throwable`, которые производят соответствующие реакции у `mView`.

Сам тест прост, однако сама инфраструктура теста сложная (к примеру это можно тестировать с помощью библиотеки **Mockito**). Нужно сделать несколько моков:

- объект, где находится метод `getResults`
- `mCompositeDisposable`
- `ApiUtils.getApi()` (не знаю что оно собой представляет)
- `mView`

Возможно, что-то придется отрефакторить. Суть сводиться к тому, чтобы измениться поведение всех методов внешних, по отношению к тестируемому методу, объектов. Моки позволяют делать так, что например, вызов `ApiUtils.getApi().getResponse(textSearch)` на самом деле ничего не будет делать, а вернет готовый `response` объект / или `throwable` (в зависимости от того, что хотим проверить - или отработало или ошибка), а `mCompositeDisposable.add()` ничего никуда добавлять не будет, а просто имитирует это действие также все методы `mView` ничего не будут делать, важен лишь сам факт, они были вызваны или были вызваны с конкретным параметром(ами).

Таким образом, все сводится к паре тестов (довольно длинных):

1. вызвали метод `getResults` с каким-то значение (неважно с каким),
   вернулся response и как факт корректной работы были вызваны методы
   `mView` `showRefresh`,  `hideRefresh`, `showResults`(c конкретным значением
   `response.getResults()`)
2. вызвали метод `getResults` с каким-то значение (неважно с каким), вернулся `throwable` и как факт корректной работы были вызваны методы `mView` `showRefresh`, `hideRefresh`, `showError`.

Я, конечно, могу сильно заблуждаться в правильности такого подхода, но я вижу его вполне разумным. Собственно, все вышеописанное выглядит какой-то магией на первый взгляд, но если почитать документацию к [Moсkito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html), которая очень короткая и четко все описывающая, то все встанет на свои места, ну и неделя на вникание/пробование потребуется. Удачи )

Comment: @ApiUtils.getApi() это API Retrfoit2. Вот вы пишите, что проверить showResult(), что там после запроса определенные данные. Но проблема в том, что я получаю данные со стороннего API, где меняются данные. Получается, что со временем тест этот будет проваливаться, так как там изменились данные?

Comment: Библиотека Mokito позволяет делать моки - это такой объект от конкретного класса, который внутри себя условно представляет структуру вашего класса (все его методы с их возвращаемыми типами и типами параметров методов). В зависимости от вида мока можно выполнять код вызываемого метода, но заменять возвращаемое значение (на какое-то свое), а можно не выполнять код вызываемого метода, но возвращать то, что требуется. Таким образом, используя второй вариант, методы ретрофита ничего не будут делать - будет имитация вызова и возвращение нужного значения.